# QgsCoordinateTransform doesn't work correctly for outbound coordinates using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.28

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3, extents

I'm developing a plugin which, as part of its functionality, needs to retrieve the coordinates of the current canvas extent in WGS84.

I use `qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().extent()` to retrieve the extent whose coordinates are expressed in the project's current CRS. If this CRS is not WGS84, I use the `transformBoundingBox` method of the `QgsCoordinateTransform` to convert the coordinates to WGS84.
I've noticed that if the source coordinates exceed the bounds of the origin CRS, the destination coordinates are invalid. Specifically, Y values are valid, but X values are not.

Here's a script I developed to investigate. It adds 2 layers to the project. The first contains the current canvas extent polygon in its original CRS. The second layer contains the current canvas extent polygon in WGS84.

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsRectangle, QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsProject, QgsRenderContext, QgsRasterLayer, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor

current_crs = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()
wgs84_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

CRS_converter = QgsCoordinateTransform(current_crs, wgs84_crs, QgsProject.instance())

currentCRS_rectangle = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
wgs84_rectangle = CRS_converter.transformBoundingBox(currentCRS_rectangle)

points_currentCRS = [
    QgsPointXY(currentCRS_rectangle.xMinimum(), currentCRS_rectangle.yMaximum()),
    QgsPointXY(currentCRS_rectangle.xMaximum(), currentCRS_rectangle.yMaximum()),
    QgsPointXY(currentCRS_rectangle.xMaximum(), currentCRS_rectangle.yMinimum()),
    QgsPointXY(currentCRS_rectangle.xMinimum(), currentCRS_rectangle.yMinimum())
]
bbox_geometry_currentCRS = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points_currentCRS])
bbox_polygon_currentCRS = QgsFeature()
bbox_polygon_currentCRS.setGeometry(bbox_geometry_currentCRS)
bbox_layer_currentCRS = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:{}".format(int(str(current_crs.authid()).split(":")[1])), "BoundingBox_currentCRS", "memory")
bbox_layer_currentCRS.dataProvider().addFeatures([bbox_polygon_currentCRS])

points_wgs84 = [
    QgsPointXY(wgs84_rectangle.xMinimum(), wgs84_rectangle.yMaximum()),
    QgsPointXY(wgs84_rectangle.xMaximum(), wgs84_rectangle.yMaximum()),
    QgsPointXY(wgs84_rectangle.xMaximum(), wgs84_rectangle.yMinimum()),
    QgsPointXY(wgs84_rectangle.xMinimum(), wgs84_rectangle.yMinimum())
]
bbox_geometry_wgs84 = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points_wgs84])
bbox_polygon_wgs84 = QgsFeature()
bbox_polygon_wgs84.setGeometry(bbox_geometry_wgs84)
bbox_layer_wgs84 = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:{}".format(int(str(wgs84_crs.authid()).split(":")[1])), "BoundingBox_wgs84", "memory")
bbox_layer_wgs84.dataProvider().addFeatures([bbox_polygon_wgs84])

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
qgs_prj = QgsProject.instance()

canvas.mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(current_crs)
symbols = bbox_layer_currentCRS.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255, 20, 147))
symbol.setOpacity(0.25)
qgs_prj.addMapLayer(bbox_layer_currentCRS)

canvas.mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(wgs84_crs)
symbols = bbox_layer_wgs84.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255, 20, 147))
symbol.setOpacity(0.25)
qgs_prj.addMapLayer(bbox_layer_wgs84)
```

If I run this script when the current canvas extent is contained within the bounds of the project's current CRS, I see that the polygons in my 2 layers are identical.

[image]

On the other hand, if I run this script when the current canvas extent is outside the bounds of the project's current CRS, I find that the polygon of my first layer is correct, but the one of the second layer is not.

[image]

Is there a way to ensure correct conversion of source coordinates beyond the limits of the original CRS? Perhaps I'm not using the `QgsCoordinateTransform` properly.

Comment: This is like wondering why a car going 500 mph might have some issues around tight corners when it is fine at 10mph, it just is because there are limitations to the car (and physics). You expect it to work as well outside the bounds of the crs as inside when the bounds are there for a reason and going outside them is going to have unexpected and unreliable results

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm well aware of what the word "limit" means and I'm not really surprised by this behavior. Nevertheless, the fact that the Y coordinates are correct and that the X coordinates always seem to be so close to the limits of the destination CRS suggests to me that there may be a logic.
Maybe someone can explain this logic to me.